# Problem formating formData to upload image from local directory into imgur using node.js

Tags: node.js, form-data, imgur, node.js-fs

I'm tryin to upload an image located in a directory to Imgur, and it's giving error. I feel like the error can ocurr when appending the image to the formData.

```
    const directoryPath = './imagesExercises/1dumbbellflyes.png';
    
        const buffer = fs.readFileSync(directoryPath);
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('image', buffer);
        try {
            const response = await fetch('https://api.imgur.com/3/upload', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Client-ID ${process.env.IMGUR_CLIENT_ID}`,
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                },
                body: formData
            });
            const imgurImageLink = await response.json();
            console.log(imgurImageLink);
            console.log(imgurImageLink.data.link);
} catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
```

And it's giving the error:

```
{
  status: 400,
  success: false,
  data: { error: 'Bad Request', request: '/3/upload', method: 'POST' }
}
undefined
```

Comment: are you getting process.env.IMGUR_CLIENT_ID ?

Comment: also user fs.createReadStream in form data

Comment: try removing `Content-Type` header, if that doesn't work try some of the examples here: [Post data using a file](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch#post-data-using-a-file)

Comment: @HarikrushnaPatel I do get the IMGUR_CLIENT_ID. And you mean reading the image using createReadStream instead of readFileSync ?

Comment: yes , also as per documentation for upload image you need to use 

``https://api.imgur.com/3/image``

https://apidocs.imgur.com/#c85c9dfc-7487-4de2-9ecd-66f727cf3139